# Secure Store .... EndpointNotFoundException: Secure Store Service did not performed the operation.

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, msdn

I have been having trouble with Secure Store. When I deploy or do an IISRESET, my Secure Store works for a few hours, but then Secure Store Dies, and I get below Error:

```
System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: Secure Store Service did not 
performed the operation. 


System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: Secure Store Service did not 
performed the operation. at    Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService.Server.
SecureStoreServiceApplicationProxy.Execute[T](String operationName, Boolean 
validateCanary, ExecuteDelegate`1 operation) at icrosoft.Office.SecureStoreService.
Server.SecureStoreServiceApplicationProxy.GetCredentials(Guid rawPartitionId, 
String applicationId) at 
Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService.Server.SecureStoreProvider.
GetCredentials(String appId)
```

I am running out of options, that's why I am asking here.

I have already looked into Nulling objects ... as from what I read here:  http://davidlozzi.com/tag/secure-store-service/

Here is my code to retrieve my Secure Store Credentials..

```
   public static Dictionary<string, string> GetCredentials(string applicationID)
    {
        var credentialMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var serviceContext = SPServiceContext.Current;
        var secureStoreProvider = new SecureStoreProvider { Context = serviceContext };

        using (var credentials = secureStoreProvider.GetCredentials(applicationID))
        {
            var fields = secureStoreProvider.GetTargetApplicationFields(applicationID);
            for (var i = 0; i < fields.Count; i++)
            {
                var field = fields[i];
                var credential = credentials[i];
                var decryptedCredential = ToClrString(credential.Credential);

                credentialMap.Add(field.Name, decryptedCredential);
                credentials[i].Dispose();
            }

        }
        serviceContext = null;
        secureStoreProvider = null;
        return credentialMap;
    }
```

.. But it doesnt seem to work either.

Any Suggestions would be very helpful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See the code below - we use it in our back-end Timer jobs and front-end usecases without a problem for months now.

The only difference seems to be the recreation of `SPServiceContext` every time a credential is requested. Try that instead of reusing the current context.

```
public class ExternalCredentialsRepository
{
    private readonly string webUrl;

    public ExternalCredentialsRepository(string webUrl)
    {
        this.webUrl = webUrl;
    }

    public NetworkCredential GetCredentials(string applicationId)
    {
        var credentialMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        using (var site = new SPSite(webUrl))
        {
            var serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
            var secureStoreProvider = new SecureStoreProvider {Context = serviceContext};

            using (var credentials = secureStoreProvider.GetCredentials(applicationId))
                PopulateCredentialsMap(secureStoreProvider, credentials, applicationId, credentialMap);
        }

        string userName = credentialMap["Windows User Name"];
        string domain = credentialMap["Windows Domain"];
        string password = credentialMap["Windows Password"];

        return new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);
    }

    private static void PopulateCredentialsMap(SecureStoreProvider secureStoreProvider, SecureStoreCredentialCollection credentials, string applicationId, Dictionary<string, string> credentialMap)
    {
        var fields = secureStoreProvider.GetTargetApplicationFields(applicationId);

        for (var i = 0; i < fields.Count; i++)
        {
            var field = fields[i];
            var credential = credentials[i];
            var decryptedCredential = ExtractString(credential.Credential);

            credentialMap.Add(field.Name, decryptedCredential);
        }
    }

    private static string ExtractString(SecureString secureString)
    {
        var ptr = Marshal.SecureStringToBSTR(secureString);

        try
        {
            return Marshal.PtrToStringBSTR(ptr);
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.FreeBSTR(ptr);
        }
    }
}
```